# Regex to select csv values from string

Tags: c#, regex

I typically have a string that might look like the following and I would like to extract the contents and parse it into an array by splitting the values.

```
COUNT(123,453,123)
```

For validation reasons it might so happen that a comma is left on the end of contents like so.

```
COUNT(123,453,123,)
```

My code so far is as follows.

```
Regex.Match(testString, @"(?<=\().+?(?=\))").ToString().Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

It works fine for the first case but will throw an exception on the latter case.

**Exception**

*input string was not in a correct format*

How can I make the regex ignore a comma if there is no additional number after it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<=\().+?(?=,?\))

             ^^
```

Just add that to `lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rO0yD8/14